# Does PowerShell support private static variables in a PS-module

Tags: powershell

Does PowerShell supports private static variables in a PowerShell module (like a private static variable in C#)? If so, do I need a "special" syntax for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [about_Scopes documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx).

There is a `script` scope:

```
 Script: 
        The scope that is created while a script file runs. Only
        the commands in the script run in the script scope. To
        the commands in a script, the script scope is the local
        scope.
```

Also worth reading - Restricting Without Scope:

```
Modules:
        You can use a Windows PowerShell module to share and deliver
        Windows PowerShell tools. A module is a unit that can contain
        cmdlets, scripts, functions, variables, aliases, and other useful
        items. Unless explicitly defined, the items in a module are not
        accessible outside the module. Therefore, you can add the module to
        your session and use the public items without worrying that the
        other items might override the cmdlets, scripts, functions, and other
        items in your session.


        The privacy of a module behaves like a scope, but adding a module
        to a session does not change the scope. And, the module does not have
        its own scope, although the scripts in the module, like all Windows
        PowerShell scripts, do have their own scope.
```

Comment: With all respect, this doesn't answer the question: "**Does PowerShell support private static variables in a PS-module?**", I guess the answer is actually **`No`**.

Comment: @iRon Thank you for the feedback. And yes you are right, there is nothing like private static variables in a PS-module - I just wanted to reference PS scopes to see what is possible...